# How to get the hour to restart on a clockTower once it reaches a certain value

Tags: java, real-time-clock

When I run my program the hour does not restart back to `zero` instead it keeps going.

For example if `Tower A` is at `0` and `Tower B` is at `23`  and I want to add `8 hours`

My code outputs:
`Tower A` is at `9` and `Tower B` is at `32`.

```
public void advanceClock(int numHours)

{

    if (hour >= 0 && hour <= 23)

    {
    hour = hour + numHours;
    advanceOneHour();
    }   
}
```

This is what the instance method should do:

`public void advanceClock (int numHours)`

Advances the current hour on this ClockTower by numHours hours. The hour will always be between `0` (midnight) and `23` (i.e., the next hour after `23` is `0`).

Expected output is:
`Tower A` is at `8` and `Tower B` is at `7`.

Comment: create a reset() method and call that

Comment: Even if i reset the value how do i get it to keep adding the correct amount. The leftover value of numHours from before the value needed to get reset

Comment: `hour = (hour + numHours) % 24` should do the trick.

Comment: you can create an advance method that adds only one hour, and call it the x times you are passed as hours. that way, all you need to do is: if ( time == 23.00 ) time = 0.00; else time +1 hour

Comment: Even when I try hour = (hour + numHours) % 24 my output comes out to Tower A is at 9 and Tower B is at 8.

Comment: That's because you then call `advanceOneHour()`, I suppose